# Codeanywhere (IDE) - Unable to browse folders

Tags: ftp, ide, directory, codeanywhere

I use CodeAnywhere as an IDE. It's been working great for me. All the sudden, I logged in and was unable to view any folders in any of my projects. All it shows is a blank HTML file. I'm at my wits' end and CodeAnywhere's support is utterly useless.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

[CodeAnywhere Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9o0J.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I can see that you're accessing via FTP all those servers/folders, is that correct?
Have you tried accessing these servers with other ftp tools, like filezilla? And if so, the files are still there?

I've had a similar problem while configuring a new FTP connection, where the `Initial dir` I entered was blocked to the `Username` I was using to connect, thus showing a blank connection. I recommend double checking the configuration you're using and also making sure the files you're trying to find are still there, with filezilla or another ftp tool.